# RestEasy / Jackson JsonRawValue not working in Wildfly

Tags: json, jackson, jax-rs, wildfly

I have a simple POJO that I'm returning from a Jaxrs webservice in Wildfly

```
import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonRawValue;

public class AttributeFieldListDTO {

    private Integer attributeFieldListId;
    private String name;
    private String category;

    @JsonRawValue
    private String fields;


    public Integer getAttributeFieldListId() {
        return attributeFieldListId;
    }

    public void setAttributeFieldListId(Integer attributeFieldListId) {
        this.attributeFieldListId = attributeFieldListId;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public void setCategory(String category) {
        this.category = category;
    }


    public String getFields() {
        return fields;
    }

    public void setFields(String fields) {
        this.fields = fields;
    }
}
```

How ever, my fields data is getting quoted and the newlines are getting escaped. I haven't configured anything on the server, as I thought Jackson was the default.

Any idea why the serialization isn't respecting the JsonRawValue annotation?

Comment: Please add imports.  Jackson2 is the default on wildfly.

Answer (score 2):

This is the correct import:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonRawValue;
```

To get it to compile, I added this dependency:

```
         <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: this also solved it for me in a non-wildfly related project